# How to copy anonymous column List to session

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I tried to copy the list to session but it's null I tried below code.

```
var questions = dbContext.Sft_Set.Where(s => s.Sft_Set_ID == currentSet)
                  .Select(s => new
                  {
                      id = s.Sft_Set_ID,
                      qid = s.Sft_QuestionID,
                      qName = s.Sft_Question.Q_Question,
                      qtype = s.Sft_Question.Q_Type
                  }).ToList();

Session["questionList"] = questions;
var list = Session["questionList"] as List<Sft_Set>;
```

Comment: Your select creates anonymous type instances, not `Sft_Set` instances therefore `as List<Sft_Set>` returns null

Comment: What is Session?  Is it a table in the database?

Comment: @jdweng It is probably a [Controller.Session Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.session?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2).

Comment: Why would you expect to convert from `List<SomeAnonymousType>` to `List<Sft_Set>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

The blocking word is `anonymous`. Youn can't unbox an anonymous type because, there is nothing known in the box. (I haven't try with `dynamic` but not the more elegant way)

as said by vc, the code should be:

```
var questions = dbContext.Sft_Set.Where(s => s.Sft_Set_ID == currentSet)
              .Select(s => new
              Sft_Set {  // <===============================
                  id = s.Sft_Set_ID,
                  qid = s.Sft_QuestionID,
                  qName = s.Sft_Question.Q_Question,
                  qtype = s.Sft_Question.Q_Type
              }).ToList();

Session["questionList"] = questions;
var list = Session["questionList"] as List<Sft_Set>;
```

or more probably:

```
public class SomeDTOType {
    public int id {get; set;}
    public int qid {get; set;}
    public string qname {get; set;}
    public int qtype {get; set;}
}

var questions = dbContext.Sft_Set.Where(s => s.Sft_Set_ID == currentSet)
              .Select(s => new
              SomeDTOType {  // <===============================
                  id = s.Sft_Set_ID,
                  qid = s.Sft_QuestionID,
                  qName = s.Sft_Question.Q_Question,
                  qtype = s.Sft_Question.Q_Type
              }).ToList();

Session["questionList"] = questions;
var list = Session["questionList"] as List<SomeDTOType>;
```

Answer (score 1):

As @vc74 said in his comment `list` is null because you've put a List of anonymous objects into the Session and try to cast this list using the `as` keyword to a `List<Sft_Set>` Objects.

Because there your List of anonymous objects cannot be casted to a `List<Sft_Set>`, you get a result of `null`. This doesn't mean that your Session["questionList"] is null, it just means that it cannot be casted.

So you have the following options to solve that issue:

- Don't use a projection within your Linq Query and put the List into your session
- Create a class for your projection so that you don't use anonymous objects
- declare `list` as `dynamic` and don't use the as operator. This means that you won't have intellisense and compile time checks for `list`

**Here is a code Sample for the second option:**

```
public class Question
{
   public int id {get;set;} // or whatever datatype your id is
   public int qid {get;set;} // or whatever datatype your qid is
   public string qName {get;set;} // chose a datatype that makes sense here
   public string qType {get;set;} // chose a datatype that makes sense here
}

/// .....

var questions = dbContext.Sft_Set.Where(s => s.Sft_Set_ID == currentSet)
                  .Select(s => new Question
                  {
                      id = s.Sft_Set_ID,
                      qid = s.Sft_QuestionID,
                      qName = s.Sft_Question.Q_Question,
                      qtype = s.Sft_Question.Q_Type
                  }).ToList();

Session["questionList"] = questions;
var list = Session["questionList"] as List<Question>;
```